# Creating and Installing Upstream Debian Packages without Breaking Distro Integrity

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

My use case:

I am running Debian Squeeze Backport 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 over an Asus p-67 Sabertooth mobo | i72600K proc ... I plan on doing a little speed-stepping so I wanted to use lm-sensors to monitor my processors speeds ... However, the most current lm-sensors version in debian stable is 1:3.1.2-6 and the lm-sensors version that supports my board's chip is 1:3.3.2 ...

At first I simply ran Make and built the app which worked ... However, I don't want to do that ... bad habit. So, I decided to go about building a .deb using dh_make. The install works ... yet, I now have the problem of having an upstream, detached package installed out of integrity with Apt.

How can I keep the package I created installed and yet still maintain system integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to have a try mixing multiple versions of the system, ie., stable and testing. Setting the priority of different versions in /etc/apt/preferences.d, stable higher than testing, and the system will prefer stable packages to testing ones. Then, you may want to

```
 apt-get install lm-sensors/testing
```

so as to install the testing version of lm-sensors, as well as its all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks ... That's what I should have done ... But, I took the 'hard way'. Downloaded, compiled and made a deb and then apt-pinned the pkg @ 1001 ... Now I know ...